# request via wireless network vs mobile network in android

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, androidhttpclient

i have following lines of code to check whether device has internet or not.

```
boolean hasInternet = false;
HttpURLConnection urlc = null;
try {
    urlc = (HttpURLConnection)
           (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204")
           .openConnection());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
urlc.connect();
hasInternet =  (urlc.getResponseCode() == 204 &&
                urlc.getContentLength() == 0);
```

when i use wireless internet connection everything is fine and hasInternet value is true. but when i use mobile network provider, the value of hasInternet is always false but i can open any site in my mobile browser. what seems to be the problem?

Comment: try increasing connecttimeout as it may be possible your mobile network is slower then wireless network. try setting it to 5 sec or 10 sec

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela i tried with 10 sec time out but nothing achieved!

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to check for isNetwork available in mobile device:

```
public static boolean isNetwork(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: this is surely a good solution but sometimes it happens your device is connected to wifi but your wifi router has internet connectivity problems so it is always good to put a check by accessing some URL. i have experienced this issue practically in few of my projects and based on that i m commenting.

Comment: i have this code before those lines. this is not the point i think. i'm trying to post an http request via httpclient of apache. it's same. using wireless has no problem but using mobile network provider it won't send the request. maybe my mobile network provider uses some proxy or banned something!

Comment: Very good point @RajenRaiyarela never thought about it, I will use your concept too from now.